Why am I getting an empty transaction history from Apple's new StoreKit2 endpoint?
I'm working on a React Native app and using the following libraries to handle in-app purchases and subscriptions:
Purchase management: react-native-iap
Transaction verification on server side: apple-store-server-api
I'm using the new StoreKit2 API endpoint for subscription retrieval , and I’ve been able to successfully reach the endpoint. However, I'm encountering an issue:
Problem
When I use getTransactionHistory or getTransactionInfo with the Apple Store Server API, I always get an empty array of transactions.
This happens despite the fact that:
The purchase is successful in the sandbox environment.
I can see the transaction in StoreKit Test in Xcode, and it has an expiry date.
The transaction in the sandbox provides a transactionId, which I’m using to query the API.
What I Tried
I tested with sandbox:
The purchase completes successfully, and I get a transactionId from the sandbox.
When I send this transactionId to the Apple Store Server API (using getTransactionHistory or getTransactionInfo), I receive an empty array.
I tested with StoreKit Test:
Using StoreKit Test in Xcode, I can verify that the transaction is marked as finished and has an expiry date.
However, since StoreKit Test doesn’t generate a valid transactionId, I cannot test it with the Apple endpoint.
Environment
React Native app using react-native-iap.
Backend powered by the apple-store-server-api library.
Testing in both sandbox and StoreKit Test environments.
The subscription is configured correctly in my StoreKit configuration file and Apple Developer account.
Questions

Why is the Apple Store Server API returning an empty transaction
history when the sandbox purchase is successful and the transactionId
is provided and accepted by the API?
Is there something specific I need to configure to fetch transactions
for sandbox users?
How do I properly query transactions when using StoreKit Test, given
the lack of a valid transactionId?
Do I even need to get the expiry date to check if the subscription is
valid? If not, what’s the recommended approach to determine
subscription validity with StoreKit2?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
